# jQuery onclick placer doing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input on my index page:

```
<input type="button" name="goReplaceAll" value="Go" id="allReplaceGo" style="cursor:hand;" />
```

And an onclick call from jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#allReplaceGo').click(replaceAll);
});
function replaceAll(){ alert('a'); }
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. When I instead use onclick="replaceAll()" within the HTML, I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: replaceAll is not defined

I am unable to figure out a connection between these errors, or any possible cause.

The code is currently live at http://www.texturepacker.net

Edit: Looks like I get two different results in Firefox and Chrome, Chrome does nothing while Firefox alert('a')'s once the page loads. Now I'm just plain confused?

Edit: Seemingly an unrelated syntax error later in my code was breaking the call. Now replaceAll() is called when the dom loads, my question is now why isn't replaceAll() being launched onclick and instead once the dom loads, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/G5vvy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like a **syntax error** here...

Line 196 in you script file says

```
$(this).("src",tmpSrc);
```

It is supposed to be

```
$(this).attr("src",tmpSrc);
```

Fix that and it should be all fine..

Also on line 7

```
$('#allReplaceGo').live("click",replaceAll());
```

is supposed to be

```
$('#allReplaceGo').live("click",replaceAll);
```

Also as of version 1.7 **.live()** is deprecated. try using **.on()** instead

Comment: Actually, fix that and then the real problem will be apparent.  The code in the question is not the code being used in the page.  The code in the question is good, the code on that page is using `live` and invoking the method rather than passing it to live.

Comment: Yes true, the code works fine.. but the code does not seem to compile for the OP because of this right.. So was just pointing it out

Comment: Also this is supposed to be $('#allReplaceGo').live("click",replaceAll); instead of what the OP wrote

Comment: Good catch, I was asked to try .live on IRC. After fixing the syntax error mentioned the code works as expected. Thanks for the .on tip too.

Answer (score -2):

That happens, probably, because the function replaceAll is outside the jQuery scope.
Try to put her inside the $(document).ready scope.

Comment: A function can be outside the scope of the DOm ready event .. It is better to include them outside , coz of scoping issues, If you want to call the function outside the DOM ready event

Answer (score -2):

Your code should look like

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#allReplaceGo').click(function(){
           replaceAll()
        });
    });
    function replaceAll(){ alert('a'); }
```

Comment: That is actually unnecessary.  If no parameters are being passed to the function it is perfectly valid (and more concise) to pass just the function.

Comment: I've tested this code and works for me. Inspecting your js file marks an error on line 188 "$(this).("src",tmpSrc);" for an uncaught string.
Probably that is making you code not to work properly

Comment: Hmm, good catch, fixing that means the alert('a'); is now launched, seemingly fixing the problem. My follow up question now is why is replaceAll() being called when the dom loads instead of when the #allReplaceGo button is clicked?

Comment: Remove the () for calling the funcion.
.live("click", replaceAll)